# Differentiate if the app became inactive because the home button being pressed or an incomming phone call

Tags: iphone, ios4, interruptions

I know that whenever the app becomes inactive, the UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification local notification will be posted. In the opposite suituation, the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification notification will be posted.

A client want the app to act differently according to the interruption, he wants the app to close when the home button but to remain active if the user receives a phone call. It doesn't seem to be possible, I'm correct ?. If It's possible how can I do It ?

Edit: I know how to close my app whenever an interruption is received , my question is if it's possible to differentiate if the cause of the interruption was the home button being pressed or an incomming phone call, so my app responds differently in each case.

Answer (score 1):

Using `CTCallCenter` notifications allows you to differentiate between incoming call or send-to-background using Home or multitasking tray reasonably reliably.

Answer (score -2):

If you want the app to quit when the home button is pressed, you should set the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key to `YES` in the app's Info.plist file.  If you edit the plist in Xcode, this key is displayed as `Application does not run in background`.

Then you can handle all of your termination in response to the `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` notification (or equivalently, in the appDelegate's `applicationWillTerminate:` method.

More information here:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Comment: I know how to close my app whenever an interruption is received , my question is if it's possible to differentiate if the cause of the interruption was the home button being pressed or an incomming phone call, so my app responds differently in each case...by the way, I didn't down-vote your post, sorry for that